# How to hide header on scroll down, show on scroll up like linkedin menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new at javascript css and html. My head realy blow up while trying to do what I need. I found [this code](http://codepen.io/AdobeWordPress/pen/tigrx) to inspire me but I could not make it to be suitable for my requirement. I created [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h64s4vy2/2/). What I realy need something like linkedin menu but my my main header menu div is not fixed. I want if user scroll down my red menu stick to top and if scroll up it hides and if user reach top of scroll my red menu stick bottom of main (blue) menu. Can you guys tell me how I can manage to do that.

my html code is

```
    <div class="mainMenu"><h2>Some Menu here</h2></div>
    <div class="yapiskan">STICKY MENU</div>
    <div id="lipsum" >
       <p>Duis vel faucibus purus. Nam interdum erat at bibendum tincidunt. Integer tempor hendrerit purus, sit amet fringilla felis imperdiet tempus. Nullam a sem eget velit mattis</p>
       <img src="http://www.adobewordpress.com/ads/300x250.jpg">
       <p>Morbi varius faucibus nulla ut pharetra. Vestibulum sed sapien turpis. Sed diam felis, ullamcorper vel augue id, porta porta nibh. Mauris interdum elit ac metus fermentum, eu porttitor purus venenatis. In nec metus vitae augue mattis porta in at erat. Sus</p>
    </div>
```

MY css code

```
    body{background-color:white; padding-top:10px; font:100 14px 'Open Sans'}

    #lipsum{width:690px; margin:30px auto; color:#34495e;text-align:justify}
    .mainMenu{height:40px;background-color: #5C9DD7; color:white;width:100%;}
    img{float:left; margin:0 10px 10px 0;}

    .yapiskan{
      background-color:#e74c3c; 
      color:white; 
      font-size:24px; 
      padding:5px; 
      text-align:center;  
      width:100%; 
      transition: top .5s;
    }
```

Comment: Please include the code that you found in your question, as sites go down time-to-time or sometimes cease existing altogether, and it'd be better to have the relevant pieces of code on SO.

Comment: You should at least show some code where you tried to achieve this, some research you did. There are plenty of sites talking about such kind of menus.

Comment: but in my question I already put the links which I got from my search and I tried it in my project and it did not become what I wanted. What I need was something like linkedin menu. when you open linkedin there are 2 menu over eachother one is fixed to top and another is just bottom of it and it show/hide by scroll action.But I need this fixed top menu should not be fixed just the second one should be navigetable by scroll action

Comment: By the way, if your content is laid out inside of an `overflow: scroll/auto` area, it's **impossible** to implement this feature. Use CSS `transform: translateY()` instead to support all the scrolling and interactions with fixed headers. It also can solve billions of problems with fixed bugs and auto-scroll on input boxes focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your example modified [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h64s4vy2/4/)

Add to you JS with at least jquery 1.11^:

```
    //initialize j
    var j = 0;

    // function scroll for viewport
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        console.log(j + ' first - variable value j');

        //var top with your menu .yapiskan
        var top = ($('.yapiskan').offset() || { "top": NaN }).top;
        if (isNaN(top)) {
            console.log("something is wrong, no top");  
        } else if (j < top){
            //hide menu
            $('.yapiskan').slideUp();
        } else if (j > top){
            //show menu
            $('.yapiskan').slideDown();
        }
        j = top;
        console.log(j+' last - variable value j');
    });
```

Add to your CSS:

```
/*Add position fixed*/
#mainMenu{position:fixed;top:0;}
.yapiskan{position:fixed;top: 40px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to point you to the right direction..

`$(window).on('scroll' function() {})` will run function on window scroll

`el.offset().top` will get the `el`'s position within the page

`$(window).scrollTop()` will get the current scroll position

now all you have to do is run `if(el.offset().top ==== $(window).scrolltop())` to do what you want