# Show header when scrolled up enough part of page and with a specific speed

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I was trying to do something in jquery like:

1. Hide the header when user scrolls down
2. When user scrolls up a little, don't show the header
3. When user scrolls up a bit more, but, with a slow speed which means the user might be reading the content, still don't show the header
4. When user scrolls up enough and with a faster speed, which means the user might want to go to top, or, want to access the navigation, SHOW THE HEADER and go to top link.

I have searched a lot, but could not find anything like this. I have tried the following:

http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi, I am not very good at javascript, still I have tried this http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/ in my code, but it gives a delay in both scroll up and down, plus speed is not considered in it at all.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with jQuery.

It has already been answered, though: [How to hide header on scroll down, show on scroll up like linkedin menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997727/how-to-hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-like-linkedin-menu)

**Edit**

A good article: https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c

Comment: Thanks, but I had already read these articles, they are not answering what I asked actually.